# Vb.net get panels colors

Tags: vb.net, winforms

```
for i = 0 to 10
    dim paneln as new panel
    paneln.backcolor = color.red
    if i = 5 then
        paneln.backcolor = color.white
    end if
    me.controls.add(paneln)
next
```

Now I want to get the color of every panel on my form

red
red
red
red
white
red
red
red
red
red

Something like:

```
For Each p As Panel In Me.Controls
    MsgBox(p.BackColor)
Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
For Each p As Panel In Me.Controls.OfType(Of Panel)()
  MessageBox.Show(p.BackColor.ToString())
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using .Net 3.5 or 4.0, you can try:

```
For Each p as Panel In Me.Controls.OfType(Of Panel)
    MessageBox.Show(p.BackColor)
Next
```

That will iterate through only the panel controls (or controls that derive from Panel), and ignore the others.  Note that this only gets the panels that are directly on the form, and not any panels that are inside container objects, like other panels.

Comment: MsgBox(p.BackColor)
 i think that BackColor.tostring fix the exeption :) but tnx

Comment: I've changed VB6-style `MsgBox` to the .Net-style `MessageBox.Show`, which should implicitly call the ToString method on p.BackColor.  And I learned today that MsgBox takes an Object as its parameter, rather than a string.